# Parse multiple Integers recieved via serial - Arduino

Tags: arduino

I want to parse two integers that are sent from one arduino to another. The integers can be between 1 and 3 digits and they can be the same but still I must be able to tell which one is which.

Tried to search the already answerd questions regarding this but cannot find any good answear.

I have tried with this on the reciever (I print the inputstring2 on a LCD screen where I also reset the Inputstring2):

```
if(incomingByte == 'b'){
 incomingByte = Serial.read();

  while(incomingByte >= '0' && incomingByte <= '9'){

 inputString2 += incomingByte;
     incomingByte = Serial.read();

}
  stringComplete2= true;//
```

The error is that I sometimes get only one of the digits if the integer is 25 I only get 2...

Sender:

```
Serial1.print('a');
Serial1.print(temp2);
Serial1.print('b');
Serial1.print(encoderValue);
Serial1.print('n');
```

Answer (score 0):

When you send the value, also send a "tail character" to indicate to the receiver that the data characters has no more characters, i.e.:

```
Serial1.print('a');
Serial1.print(temp2);
Serial1.print('a');

Serial1.print('b');
Serial1.print(encoderValue);
Serial1.print('b');
```

In this way you enclose the data in a packet (a data a), so on the receiving end you test for the start of the packet, then read the remaining characters until you read the end of the packet.